# Need an explanation of a particular security optimisation

Tags: c++, c, security, assembly, disassembly

I was reading a [book](http://www.insidepro.com/kk/012/012r.shtml) [rus] (I'm sorry, I can not find an English version at the moment) written by Kris Kaspersky explaining the philosophy and techniques of software security.

There is one example in the book. It states that the code:

```
if ( ! IsValidUser() )
{
    Message("Invalid user! Abroting...");
    Abort;
}
```

is totally insecure because it is being translated into this:

```
       CALL IsValidUser
       OR   AX,AX
       JZ   continue
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       PUSH offset str_invalid_user
       CALL Message
       CALL Abort
continue:               ; normal program execution
       ...........
```

Thus the program can be hacked by changing just one byte in a disassembler. If we change `JZ   continue` to `JMP   continue` the check would not be performed correctly.

Then Kris writes:

> the corrected version of the program in C is:

```
IsValidUser();
if (!true)
{
    Message("Invalid user! Aborting...");
    Abort;
}
```

In this version the `{...}` section will never get a control.

I don't really get how the corrected version is supposed to work. Why does he use an `if-statement` which will never be executed thus can even be removed by a compiler?

Is it kind of a typo or error? Or I'm not getting something?

Comment: That either has to be a typo, or the book is kind of useless since it's talking about *unoptimized* code.

Comment: @CodyGray it was me who failed to interpret what `the corrected version of the program` actually means. In fact it was just a quick example of how some code which seems to be secure can be totally insecure in fact. Anyway knowing potential ways your program can be hacked is always useful.

Comment: "Corrected" as in "the way it looks after the patch...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is your fault, not Kris. This is not "secure version of the user validation code", but this is the code that is obtained after the correction introduced by a hacker

Quote in Russian from this book:

> На языке Си **исправленная**
>   программа будет выглядеть так:

Google translate:

> C language **modified (or patched)** program will look
>   like this:

Comment: Thank you. Now I get it. Kris wrote `the corrected version of the program in C is: ...`. And I misinterpreted the word `corrected`... I used to think that `corrected` means `secure`.

Comment: Using *not edited* Google translation can only be excused as last resort for a poor programmer.

Comment: @SChepurin. You are right. My goal was to show that Kolyunya does not read the text of the book carefully. That was a quote from a book in Russian only for him. I added Google Translate to political correctness. I think this question and the answer is not interesting to anyone, but only Kolyunya. Sorry for the bad quality translator Google.

Comment: @SergV I actually DID read the book carefully but the phrase `CORRECTED version of the program` is ambiguous. E.g. I did misinterpret what it was supposed to mean.

Comment: @SergV- I, actually, think that this question could be interesting for many, because assembly's tricks are like programming's ancient history but knowing what is going on behind the high-level code is a must for a high-level programmer (that everyone is striving to become, i hope). My comment was about the problem that Google translated text could be hardly understandable for foreign language speaking people.

Comment: @SChepurin. I understand your comment and I agree with you. But the issue was not assembler tricks, but no proper understanding of the text book. So it was language question. Russian words "исправленная программа " were understood as "corrected version of the program", but the meaning was "modified (or patched) program". So I edited text of my answer. If you are interested in assembler tricks you can read a books by Kris Kaspersky in English (google kris kaspersky books)

Comment: @SergV - Once again, this is a *programming* related site (not translation related). The problem with wrong understanding or wrong translation is interesting for you two, may be. But for the rest of community only the code related part could be of any interest.

Comment: @SergV- Now the answer looks better.

Answer (score 1):

The author wanted to show the kind of "equivalent" code in C that would represent unconditional jump (`JMP continue`) replacing original password's check with `JZ continue`. You are right that this code (in C) has no sense but it is there only to illustrate what the hacker has done.